# Using Jackson to convert JSON file which has "#" as one of the names, namely "x5t#S256"

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a JSON name value pair which I would like to convert to a Java object.

The JSON is as follows

```json
{
    "x5t#S256": "vaule",
}
```

The below does not work because of illegal character

```java
public class Key {
     @JsonProperty
     private String x5t#S256;
}
```

As you might guess this has to do with JWKS sets, but that's not relevant for now. It seems like quite straightforward question, but I have not been able to find anything on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the original name into the annotation, and give a different name to your attribute, for example:

```
@JsonProperty("x5t#S256")
private String differentName;
```

Comment: This wokred perfectly, even when returning the object. Thanks you guys are amazing